# How can I improve this ajax script to be more efficient to scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am making my first website and I am trying to learn how to do things efficiently. How my Ajax calls are handled now seem not efficient, as an example of my strategy I will show how I filter a table:

```
$.ajax({
    'url' : '/FilterTable?Name='+$('#NameSelect').va,
    'type' : 'GET',
    },
    'success' : function(data) {              
        $('#TableBody').html(data);
    },
    'error' : function(request,error)
    {

    }
});    

<select id="NameSelect">
   <option value="%%">All</option>
   <option value="Ryan">Ryan</option>
   <option value="Jason">Jason</option>
   <option value="David">David</option>
   <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
</select>

<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody  id="TableBody">
<% ArrayOfNames.forEach(function(output){%>
<tr>
  <td><%=output.name%></td>
</tr>
<%});%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

FilterTable is a function in the middleware(express) that takes the Select value as a parameter and does a query (%% returns all) which results are set to an array called ArrayOfNames and renders a html file called Table.html with ArrayOfNames passed in also. The Table.html file consists of this.

```
  <table style="width:100%"
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody  id="TableBody">
<% ArrayOfNames.forEach(function(output){%>
<tr>
  <td><%=output.name%></td>
</tr>
<%});%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am basically just rerendering a copy and replacing it in the main, I can see this being a problem due to all that html code being sent again and again, I think it would be better to have dynamic html code in the main and just get the new variables and told to rerender itself on client side. Is this possible?

Templating engine is EJS. When more rows want to be loaded I do something similar but just append.

Comment: Depends on how large your data set is - a few 100 rows and it would be more responsive to the user if you used something like datatables and did the filtering client-side.   A few million rows and you want that all on the server as you are here.  Then depends on how many users you have - a few users and you want to render on the server (as here), a million users and you want to move more processing to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have few clients so I will just render it on the server.